# Facebook events with no hour value in start_time are returned one day early in fql

Tags: ios, facebook, timezone, facebook-fql

Since today (July 5th 2012) Facebook changed the return value for events from a unix timestamp to a string. This messed up my iOS app that displays concert dates.

I grab the event data from the event fql table.

When i look at the json i get back from Facebook, i now see a string like this: 
"2012-10-07T19:30:00+0200".

Now, if the event creator did not post a start time for the event on facebook, the api just returns "2012-10-06" - with no time attached, and it returns the event one day to early.
While the facebook page in the browser displays the event date correctly, the api returns the date one day too early.

What is going on here, am i missing something and what is the right way to handle this?

Comment: Yeah, I know. I now have the same problem.(I was working on something else, so I didn't actually notice it before you mentioned it) I had finally gotten everything working, even though fb made it more difficult by automatically converting the time from the right timezone to Pasific time first. I don't know why they bother to do that. We just end up having to convert it back to the original time zone. The time is usually correct before the conversion for whatever country the event was made in anyways. Making it a string instead of NSDecimalNumber just makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

From yesterday everything went back to unix format, i checked and found out that this kind of string ("2012-10-07T19:30:00+0200") was a bug! only some apps were receiving that and in fact the graph api explorer never used it and always used unix time...Thank you facebook, now i have to change  everything for the second time in one week.

Here's the bug link:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/415058451869226?browse=search_5001222c9ff516a78134883

Comment: say that this isn't true! are they completely insane? 
I updated my app to make it work in the new format, the new update came out today and now the app crashes again because they switched it back to the old format? thanks facebook!